# JQuery Draggable and an <object> with an SVG?

Tags: jquery, object, svg, draggable

I have an SVG file within an object tag displaying in a table cell,and I want to make the SVG draggable within the table cell using JQuery's Draggable. The code--minus the confusing bits in the  tag, looks like this:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="box">
  <table align="center" border="1">
      <tr>
          <td valign="middle">button</td>
          <td valign="top" id="objtd">
              <div id="objdiv1">
                  <object id="svgobject1">blah, blah</object>
              </div>
          </td>
          <td valign="middle">button</td>
      </tr>
```

If I set the  tag itself as draggable, draggable doesn't work. If I wrap the  tag in a , and make the  draggable, I can drag using the margin of the div, not the SVG itself. I tried setting the handle of the  to the SVG object like this:

```
$('#objdiv1').draggable({ handle: '#svgobject1' });
```

but that failed as well.

Is there any way to make the SVG object draggable by clicking and dragging the SVG itself?

I set up an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2qyCR/) in case that helps see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HTML content doesn't get to see mouse events on the contents of `<object>`. Scripts in the page can only access mouse interaction data if the plug-in responsible deliberately makes it available through a custom interface.

I suggest including the SVG content as part of the page itself, rather than using `<object>`. This means you'll have to serve the page as `application/xhtml+xml`, and add a namespace for the SVG elements. [Example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/svg_in_html_introduction). With inline SVG, the SVG elements themselves respond to mouse events and can be scripted just like the HTML elements.

The drawback of inline SVG is that it won't work on IE with the SVG plug-in. But then no-one has used the plug-in for years anyway, and IE9 will support inline SVG too.

Comment: That's what I needed to know. Thank you! I tried to vote you up, but I am a noob and can't do it yet.

Answer (score 1):

In my case ( I'm writing a chrome only app and my SVGs are in a separate file ) I was able to change the object tag to an img tag with the type attribute set to "image/svg+xml," and the src attribute set to the path to my svg file, and that solved the problem for me.

Your mileage may vary in other browsers, but if you are writing for webkit, this approach seems to work.

Comment: Yes, this approach should work fine in all recent browsers (Opera, Chrome, Firefox, IE9+). Just note that svg files referenced via img don't have scripting enabled, and that some browsers enforce other restrictions, e.g external resources inside the svg are not loaded.